# When does a Trebuchet Shoot Its Projectile?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Consider the following sling trebuchet:

[image]

While researching I found that what controls the release angle of the projectile is the angle between the 'finger' and the extension of the beam **$r_b$**, as seen below:

[image]

The way that the release pin works is when
the arm begins to swing the sling is beginning to be thrown, however once it (the end of the arm) reaches a certain point the inertia pulls the loop off the pin causing the projectile to release at that particular instance.

With different angled pins the release point will change. So one pin will make it fire more vertical than horizontal.

Assuming that the finger is parallel to the extension of the beam **$r_b$** (i.e.  = 0) then how and when can the release angle of the projectile be determined ?

Comment: I do not understand how Detail A relates to your main illustration....  I think you are asking us to explain how one aspect of the Trebuchet works.  That would seem to depend on the design.  If you can explain what is happening in Detail A, someone here could explain the physics behind it.  Otherwise we would have to research to find out what is happening in Detail A.  But that is your responsibility, not ours.

Comment: I totally agree with you. However, Detail A is only a general illustration to help visualize what a trebuchet finger is like. I am asking when does the trebuchet release the projectile when  = 0. This might be when theta equals to zero ($r_b$ is vertical) or something else that I might be missing.

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of the Trebuchet.  In particular I have no idea what is happening in Detail A.  You still seem to be asking a question about how the Trebuchet works, rather than about the physics behind it.

Comment: I have edited the question to explain how the finger (or pin) works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I still do not understand where Detail A occurs in your 1st diagram. My guess is that Detail A is the joint between the arms labelled $r_b$ and $l$.... I think I now understand how it works.  However, I think that to find the release point you will need to solve the equations of motion, because it is "triggered" by inertia, not a mechanism.

Comment: You are right. Indeed I did derive two equations of motion (for $\theta$ and $\phi $), but I am stuck because I am not certain at what point the projectile is released.  I read the following research paper http://www.uphysicsc.com/2010-GM-B-210.pdf and it says (see the paragraph below equation (36)) that the projectile will be released when the beam $r_b$ is vertical, but doesn't state why.

Comment: The condition for release would be when the contact force between the loop of the sling and the finger (in Detail A) becomes zero.  This could be the same as when the tension in the loop becomes zero.  However, if the loop slides off the finger you will have to account for the friction between the loop and the finger, which is more complicated.  So your equations have to include the forces between the loop and the finger.

Comment: The research paper says that the release point is "supposed" to be when $r_b$ is vertical.  This is an assumption, I think, not a prediction.  On p4  in para 2 the authors state that this is where M is lowest, so there is maximum transfer of energy to m.

Comment: Can this assumption be valid (and so the reason) about the condition for the release angle of the projectile?

Comment: It sounds plausible, but I think you may need to solve the equations of motion (numerically) to be sure.  Besides, you should consider what you want to achieve from the Trebuchet : maximum range?  largest KE for mass m? maximum accuracy for a given range?  If the target is tall and thin, a horizontal collision is least likely to miss;  if it is wide but low, a vertical collision has best chance of hitting.  If the target can recoil horizontally (but not vertically), a horizontal collision might not be as destructive as one from above, even if there is more KE in the horizontal collision.

Comment: I am investigating the 'best' trebuchet design for the maximum range. I appreciate your comments about target hitting and maximum damage.
By the way: feel free to post your answer to my question. (when mass M is at its lowest point)

Comment: You shoot a trebuchet, not fire it

Comment: @DirkBruere, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise my comments :

Detail A is the joint between the "long arm" labelled $r_b$ and the "short arm" labelled $l$.  The short arm is the sling.  There is no mechanism which releases the sling : it releases itself either when the tension in the sling becomes zero, or when the sling (ring) slides sideways off the "finger".

You would like to find the optimum position (ie values of angles $\theta$ and $\phi$) for releasing the sling, in order to achieve the maximum range of the projectile m.

Detail A appears to come from source [1] below.  That webpage gives the conditions for achieving maximum range (as calculated in [3]), which include releasing the projectile when the long arm makes an angle of $\theta = 45$ degrees with the vertical.  (This is described as the "initial" release position - whatever that means.)

This does not seem right to me.  Source [3] states that for the "sliding sling-shot Trebuchet" described in Detail A the optimum release angle in the author's simulation was $\theta = 18$ degrees, although this might optimise KE transfer rather than range.  The optimum release condition seems to be when the sling makes an angle of $\phi=45$ degrees with the vertical.  This seems to be correct, because the launch angle of the projectile will then be 45 degrees also, the usual condition for maximum range of a projectile.

You cite the project report in source [2] which presumes (p 1 para 1, p 4 para 2) that, in order to maximise the KE of projectile m, it should be released when angle $\theta = 0$, ie when M is at its lowest point and has minimum PE and maximum KE.  This seems plausible but I would think it needs to be verified by solving the equations of motion.  And it is not the criterion which you are using (maximum range).

**So perhaps the optimum launch conditions are when $\theta=0$ degrees and $\phi=45$ degrees.**  However, for given values of m, M, $r_b$ and $l$, you are unlikely to obtain these two conditions simultaneously.  I think you will need to "reverse engineer" the Trebuchet by selecting a combination of m, M, $r_b$ and $l$ which achieves $\phi=45$ degrees when $\theta=0$ degrees during simulation.

Source [1] explains that the angle $\phi$ at which the projectile is released can be altered by adjusting the angle $\delta$ of the finger in Detail A.  However, it does not explain how this value of $\phi$ can be predicted.  I think adjusting angle $\delta$ is a practical adjustment which you can make when you build a real Trebuchet.  It does not need to be included in your simulation.  You can simply stop the simulation when $\phi=45$ degrees and assume that the real Trebuchet will release the sling at this point. Then you adjust angle $\delta$ until the real Trebuchet does release m at this value of $\phi$.

**Conclusion:** I think that you will need to solve the equations of motion (source [1] or [2]) for the Trebuchet numerically to obtain or check the optimum launch conditions for maximum range.

[1] "Trebuchet Physics"
http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/trebuchet-physics.html

[2] "Trebuchet: The Dynamics of a Medieval Siege Engine" http://www.uphysicsc.com/2010-GM-B-210.pdf

[3] "Trebuchet Mechanics" by Donald B Siano
http://www.aemma.org/training/trebuchet/trebmath35.pdf

Comment: From deleted answer of @Randall Stevendon: Sammy Gerbil stated, "This does not seem right to me. Source [3] states that for the "sliding sling-shot Trebuchet" described in Detail A the optimum release angle in the author's simulation was θ=18 degrees, although this might optimise KE transfer rather than range. The optimum release condition seems to be when the sling makes an angle of ϕ=45 degrees with the vertical. This seems to be correct, because the launch angle of the projectile will then be 45 degrees also, the usual condition for maximum range of a projectile."

Comment: ctd "I think the reason 45 degrees is not optimal is because the projectile is being accelerated by the trebuchet, so the velocity at 18 degrees would be much higher than at 45 degrees, and therefore possibly increasing the range. There is not one answer to the question, since the acceleration and thus the velocity of the projectile at the time of release will depend on the ratio of torques of the projectile side and counterweight side.

Comment: ctd:  Also the height of the projectile at the time it released will have an effect. The swing of the sling should cause the release to occur, assuming no friction, when theta is negative (phi plus delta)."