# Maths behind a Trebuchet¹

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, mathematics

I want to throw pumpkins up in the air. More specifically, I want to throw discarded Jack-O-Lanterns about 100 M so people can shoot them up with shotguns.

Think of it as post-halloween trap shooting.

A used Jack-O-Lantern should be between 2.5-5 Kg. I want to throw it in a high arc culminating at ~100 M splat down if no one hits it first.

The finished product needs to be transported in a pickup truck so I'm thinking of an 3 M 'beam' and a 20-30 Kg counterweight with a counterweight to pumpkin pivot ratio of 1:4. I have a few lead fishing weights in the 10-15 Kg range that I'm hoping will serve as counterweights.

There is no mechanical engineering SE site yet so I'm hoping someone can help me out with the maths behind this. I'm not Sheldon Cooper but I am a journeyman machinist so any responses don't have to be completely 'dumbed down'.

As I'd like to minimize 'trial-and-error' I need a starting point before sawing 2x4's. I reckon I've got 10 days² to produce a working model.

---

¹ <sub>Yes, a slingshot or catapult would be easier but a Trebuchet is cooler.</sub>

² <sub>No, I really don't have anything better to do with my free time.</sub>

Comment: You can start by analyzing the energy of an idealized pumpkin trajector. Figure the energy of a pumpkin of mass $m$ with speed $v$ at a peak height $h$. That's your starting point. But of course your machine is less than 100% efficient at converting counter-weight potential into pumpkin energy. And here's the kicker: having *either* a rolling platform or a dangling (rather than fixed) counter-wieght improves efficiency a lot. Have both gives you only a small improvement on either. There is a paper floating around that dicusses those efficiencies, but I don't have a link handy.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'd forgotten about the benefits a rolling platform grants.

Comment: Ah, the answer to [this question that appears in the *Related* sidebar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261306/) may be helpful.

Comment: @dmckee - Yes, I was planning on a variety of interchangeable 'fingers' for different sized pumpkins.

Comment: Although there is no mechanical engineering site specifically, Mechanical Engineering is definitely within the scope of Engineering SE.   I have my doubts that this particular question is on topic there, at least in it's current form.  Perhaps adding some diagrams and asking about your analysis is potentially on-topic at engineering SE, but I can't give any promises.